# Cormen quicksort

Tags: algorithm, quicksort, data-partitioning

In the book Introduction to Algorithms, the quicksort algorithm described in the chapter Quicksort does not employ Hoare-Partitioning.

Can anyone enlighten me with the advantage of this approach over the popular hoare-partitioning. Or is it that its just a matter of choice for the author ?

Answer (score 6):

A note in the [second edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3aBookSources&isbn=0262032937%20) (the changelog since the first) says (**emphasis** mine):

> The partitioning method used for quicksort (Section 7.1) and the expected
>   linear-time order-statistic algorithm (Section 9.2) is different. We now use the
>   method developed by Lomuto, which, along with indicator random variables,
>   **allows for a somewhat simpler analysis**. The method from the first edition, due
>    to Hoare, appears as a problem in Chapter 7.